# Crash after adding 8G memory?

Tags: laptop, memory, arch-linux

I have a laptop, Vaio EB47. I run ArchLinux x86_64, kernel 3.11.1, swap 2G.
I added a 8G memory stick(1600Hz) in it yesterday.
But when its memory reaches 1G, it crashes.
I run memtest86+ to try to test the 8G memory, but it reboots.
I'm very confused, any idea? Is the memory broken? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that it is that your model of laptop doesn't support 8GB sticks. But rather at most 4GB sticks, although 2 of them.

Comment: you should check the manual before buying hardware. refer to @DanD. 's comment.

Comment: I've changed to 4G sticks and it really works. Thanks.